# Insertion in a binary search tree(data stored at leaf node only)

Tags: haskell, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm using Haskell for this class I'm in and I have to make an insertion of in a binary search tree with recursion. Here is my tree definition:

> data Tree = Leaf Int | Branch Tree Tree

An example would be:

> tree1 = Branch ((Branch (Leaf 2) (Leaf 4)) (Branch (Leaf 6) (Leaf 10)))

My insert function should get a Tree and an Int and return a Tree:

> insert :: Tree -> Int -> Tree

I just cant understand how to go about this problem.

edit:
I know pattern matching. Here is what i thought.

```hs
insert :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
insert (Leaf i) j = if (i > j) than Branch (Leaf j) (Leaf i)
                    else Leaf i
insert (Branch l r) j = Branch (insert l j) (insert r j)
```

I know this is wrong. It gets the value inserted more than once if there are two or more numbers greater than j.

edit2:
So I followed @Willem Van Onsem suggestion and got this:

```
infimum :: Tree -> Int

infimum (Leaf i) = i;
infimum (Branch l r) = infimum r

insert :: Tree -> Int -> Tree
insert (Leaf i) j = if (j > i) then Branch (Leaf i) (Leaf j)
                    else Branch (Leaf j) (Leaf i)
insert (Branch l r) j = if (j > (infimum l)) then Branch l (insert r j)
                        else Branch (insert l j) r
```

It works. I guess it cant be done with one function only.

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, which leads me to believe that the implicit question is "write my code for me." Please edit your question to show an attempt and/or a specific question. In the meantime, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I thought of asking from left to right if the number I'm trying to insert is lesser than the integer inside the leaf but it keeps inserting afterwards when there are other numbers greater than it.

Comment: @JVFeijo Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56201300/edit) to include **specific code** with a **specific problem**. A comment with a vague idea is insufficient.

Comment: You can't build a binary search tree with that definition; it's just an inefficient encoding of a list, because there's no basis for deciding which branch to follow from any particular interior node.

Comment: A binary search tree is a tree that has the property that each node contains a unique value, and all values in the left (right) subtree of a given node `X` are smaller (greater) than the value at `X`.

Comment: A binary search tree typically has *inodes*: it contains elements in the nodes that are not leafs as well, so a better definition is `data Tree = Leaf Int | Branch Tree Int Tree`, otherwise you can only insert/search/... in *O(log^2 n)*, and it would make the algorithm *very complex*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Where did you come up with log^2(n)? The obvious search algorithm I can think of for the type defined in the question is O(n), searching every leaf in order. This is especially clear for a degenerate tree, where every left branch is a Leaf, making the tree effectively a linked list.

Comment: @amalloy: you can move down the tree, for example taking the rightmost node of the left subtree to find the largest value of the right subtree, if the tree is balanced (we can balance the tree), then we can detect that in *O(log n)*, based on that value, we search the left or right subtree, and each step we again perform the same action to detect the "spit value".

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, I've done as you suggested. What do you think?

Comment: I was looking at your most recent question, but then found it deleted. If you still want someone to look into it, please let me know.

Comment: @trincot: Where can we talk? Do I have to make another question?

Comment: You could [go back to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615112/depth-first-search-javascript-heap-out-of-memory) and undelete it (I think). Note that I would then still need some time to prepare my answer. I just don't want to waste time on it, if it is not there anymore ;-)

Comment: @trincot: I think I've found the problem already. If something else happens I'll undelete the question for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The technique you require to solve this problem is called [pattern matching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) combined with conditional branching (if / pattern guards).

You can do this either by using a `case` statement or by defining alternative function definitions with something like this:

```
maybeAddOne :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
maybeAddOne Nothing = Nothing
maybeAddOne (Just a) 
  | a < 5 = Just (a + 1)
  | otherwise = Just a
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I have searched a bit but the leaf storing the value thing is what made it difficult to find anything related. It's not even a homework is just practice exercise. I got stuck and I cant seem to understand what is the thought process for solving this problem.

Comment: Is your tree data type definition given in your question? If not you might have an easier time if you don't only store your values in the leaves of the tree but also in the internal node. Something like ```data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree | Leaf ```. @chepners comments on the question are very much relevant here as well.

Comment: Yes, it is. The exercise before that was with your tree definition and I've managed to finish. My problem began when it was required to store the value only in the leaf.

Answer (score 2):

Given your current type, you have no basis for deciding which subtree to insert the new value into; you don't have any values to compare to until you reach a leaf.

Start with a proper search tree:

```
data BST = Node Int BST BST | Empty
```

Each node contains a single value, and your `insert` function must maintain the search property, which states that for a given node `Node x left right`, all values in `left` are less than `x`, and all values in `right` are greater than `x`. (If you try to insert `x` when it is already present, you don't need to do anything: keys are unique.)

```
insert :: BST -> Int -> BST
insert Empty x = Node x Empty Empty  -- replace the empty tree with a single leaf
insert t@(Node y left right) | x == y = t  -- do nothing
                             | x < y = ...
                             | otherwise = ...
```

I leave it as an exercise to determine what to do in the cases where `x /= y`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. I agree that your tree definition would be better but it's part of the exercise the value be stored only in the leaf. Actually, the exercise before that is with the value stored in the node.